# Seeking Population Dataset of provinces in Europe?

Tags: geospatial, europe, population

I applied the following function of the R Tmap package:

```
library(tmap)
data(NLD_muni)

NLD_muni$perc_men <- NLD_muni$pop_men / NLD_muni$population * 100

tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_polygons("perc_men", palette = "RdYlBu") +
  tm_facets(by = "province")
```

if you check the data inside the Tmap package with

```
data(package="tmap")
```

You see a dataset called NLD_muni. It has detailed data of all provinces in the netherlands with its population.  I need a dataset like this (provinces + population) for further countries in Europe.

Where I can find such a dataset?

Comment: http://www.geonames.org has population data by country and province